# I've created a .xlsx file using Apache POI and It can be opened in Linux. But In windows, that file is getting corrupted and can't open using MSExcel

Tags: linux, windows, apache-poi

**Here's how I tried to do the task and it's working perfectly in Linux. But in windows, it's getting corrupted.**

HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet();

```
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i <tblAttendance.getColumns().size(); i++) {
        row.createCell(i).setCellValue(tblAttendance.getColumns().get(i).getText());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <tblItems.size(); i++) {
        row=sheet.createRow(i+1);
        for (int j = 0; j < tblAttendance.getColumns().size(); j++) {
            row.createCell(j).setCellValue(tblAttendance.getColumns().get(j).getCellData(i).toString());
        }
    }

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(btnFilter.getScene().getWindow());
    if (file!=null){
        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()+".xlsx");
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(path);
            book.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"Backup Success!",ButtonType.OK).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Something went wrong! Please try again!",ButtonType.OK).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Not fully reproducible because not a complete example given. But `HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();` creates a binary Excel workbook in BIFF file format. That should be named `*.xls` and not `*.xlsx` as done in `Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()+".xlsx");`.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your contribution and I found that if I wanna write the data to a .xlsx format, I need to go for a XSSFWorkbook and not for a HSSFWorkbook. Thanks for your commitments in this regard. Cheers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.